# nodejs: TypeError: secret must be a string or buffer

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to use the passport package for authentication. In the `passport-authenticate` callback, the `req.login` function is throwing an error: `TypeError: secret must be a string or buffer`. I checked the user argument being passed to the function and that seems right (printed below). I have no idea what else could be a source of error. I'm not sure what secret is the error referring to. Please let me know if you need more info. - Nodejs newbie.

```
 router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }
    req.login(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(`user = ${user}`);
          console.log(`${err}`);
          return next(err);
        //   console.log(`${err}`);
        // return res.status(500).json({
        //   err: 'Could not log in user'
        // });
      }

      var token = Verify.getToken(user);
              res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful!',
        success: true,
        token: token
      });
    });
  })(req,res,next);
});
```

Output:

```
user = { _id: 593f8110dd56731d6d1ad50a,
  salt: 'd8bf193acbea5d2ee50eecb88c3b8fd3fbc2316ced558270aa5699558e251a26',
  hash: '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',
  username: 'muppala',
  __v: 0,
  admin: false }
TypeError: secret must be a string or buffer
POST /users/login 500 465.600 ms - 58
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occured because the secretKey in your config.js can't be accessed. Make sure it was properly imported into verify.js.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you use the proper destructure syntax when you importing from module, like below:

`const { keyName } = require('../keys');`